How to fix color bar in canvas?
I have JavaScript code that draws vertical bars and changes their color based on the average music frequency. I tried to change the color of each bar to match the color of the previous bar, but I got a different color.


const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// Function to resize canvas
function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
resizeCanvas(); // Initial call to set canvas size

let barColors = [];
const defaultBarColors = [];

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const file = this.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      audioCtx.decodeAudioData(e.target.result, function(buffer) {
        visualize(buffer);
      });
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
});

let rev;

function visualize(buffer) {
  const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;

  const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  analyser.fftSize = 512;
  const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

  source.start();
  draw();

  function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const barWidth = Math.floor(canvas.width / 5); 
    const sensitivity = 1; 

    const frequencyBands = [
      { from: 0, to: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.2) },    // Low frequencies
      { from: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.2), to: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.4) },  // Low-mid frequencies
      { from: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.4), to: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.6) },  // Mid frequencies
      { from: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.6), to: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.8) },  // Upper-mid frequencies
      { from: Math.floor(bufferLength * 0.8), to: bufferLength }    // High frequencies
    ];

    let x = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < frequencyBands.length; i++) { // 0,1,2,3,4 
      const { from, to } = frequencyBands[i];
      const sum = dataArray.slice(from, to).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
      const avg = sum / (to - from);

      let colorValue = rev[i];

      if (avg > 0) {
        if (i > 0) {
          colorValue = rev[i - 1];
    
        } else if (i == 0) {
            colorValue = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"; // Если первая колонка, то белый цвет
        }
      } else {

        colorValue = rev[i];
      }
      


      canvasCtx.fillStyle = colorValue;
      const barHeight = Math.max((avg / 255) * canvas.height * sensitivity, canvas.height);  
      canvasCtx.fillRect(x, canvas.height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

      x += barWidth; 
    }
  }
}

function initializeCanvas() {
  const barWidth = Math.floor(canvas.width / 5);
  let x = 0;

  for (let i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    const colorValue = Math.floor(((i / 5) * (240 - 51)) + 51);
    const color = `rgb(${colorValue}, ${colorValue}, ${colorValue})`;

    defaultBarColors[i] = color;
    canvasCtx.fillStyle = color;
    canvasCtx.fillRect(x, 0, barWidth, canvas.height);

    x += barWidth;
  }  
  
  rev = defaultBarColors.reverse();
}

initializeCanvas();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    body, html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="audio/*">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>



The main part where color is setted for each bar here:
  let colorValue = rev[i];

  if (avg > 0) {
    if (i > 0) {
      colorValue = rev[i - 1];

    } else if (i == 0) {
        colorValue = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"; // Если первая колонка, то белый цвет
    }
  } else {

    colorValue = rev[i];
  }

If column is 0 (first) I change color to white. If avg > 0 I try to get color of prev bar. Othewise I set default color from rev array.
Some changes:
function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  const numBars = 5;
  let bar = 0;
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
  canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#000";
  canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const barWidth = canvas.width / numBars;

  for (let i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
    const start = Math.floor(i * bufferLength / numBars);
    const end = Math.floor((i + 1) * bufferLength / numBars);

    let sum = 0;
    for (let j = start; j < end; j++) {
      sum += dataArray[j];
    }

    const avg = sum / (end - start);

 
    if (avg > 0) {
      currentColors[i] = avg; 
    } else {
      currentColors[i] = rev[i]; // Возвращаемся к исходному цвету
    }

    const rgbColor = `rgb(${currentColors[i]}, ${currentColors[i]}, ${currentColors[i]})`;

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = rgbColor;
    canvasCtx.fillRect(bar, 0, barWidth, canvas.height);

    bar += barWidth;
  }
}


Can you check the value of avg?  I guess it is zero.

Updated the question, so, I need to change color of each bar on color of prev bar when music sounds or in color darker

It would be helpful if you could post a (link to) a minimal input file, or even hard-code the data from such a file in your code. Very few people would venture to post an answer without being able to fully test their code.

Please, link over here: https://jsfiddle.net/7jr0yxf2/1/
Just choose any mp3 file on the top of page

Any ideas here?

It is working as described for me. Please clarify your issue. One thing that seems off in there is the barHeight = Math.max( which I guess should be Math.min  instead, but otherwise when it's drawing the bar it is using the previous bar's color (the one on the left), and white for the first bar.

I think this is what you are looking for but I may be wrong.
Explanation:

I created a new array called currentColors, which will hold the current color of each bar since the old logic of updating the colorValue was not updating the colors of the bars properly.
Initializing currentColors array with the same initial colors as the defaultBarColors in the initializeCanvas function.


No, I dotn need change default background of each column. I need change it to a new color as color prev column.
